# Profiling Java WebApps

Tags: java, web-applications, profiling

While trying to profile our WebApp with JVisualVM I have the problem that a lot of the interesting stuff is hidden behind the methods of our ApplicationServer.

I would love to have a tool that would allow me to profile the complete webapp inside of the server, but without profiling the server itself or any other webapps that might be running on the same server. Basically I think the server itself should be in a good position to provide something like that, but I never heard of such a feature in any server. Is anyone aware of such a functionality?

I would like to add that I already do profile my web app with JVisualVM...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Profiling a web application without profiling the server is not really feasible, since profilers always look at the entire JVM.

You could define entry points to automatically start and stop profiling, but that is not really necessary: Just set your method call recording filters to the package of your web application and you will only see method calls in the classes that you are interested in, without the surrounding stack frames of the container.

In [JProfiler](http://www.ej-technologies.com/products/jprofiler/overview.html), this is done by opening the session settings and defining a single inclusive filter:

[image]

Disclaimer: My company develops JProfiler.

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I will try that, sounds like the best way to do it. I was thinking there might be something like a Profiling App Server out there. But of course you are right, profiling always takes the whole JVM into account. Still, I think a dedicated App Server could profile its WebApps more precisely than a tool looking from the outside in.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [VisualVm](http://visualvm.java.net/) and connect to your application server. There you can profile your application. You can connect also to a remote application server via JMX.

Answer (score 0):

You can connect VisualVM to the server's process also to profile it. See [Working with Remote Applications](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/applications_remote.html) and [Connecting to JMX Agents Explicitly](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/visualvm/jmx_connections.html) for reference.